# How to read an uneven data file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Data file is like this

```
A.1
B 
C 
D
A.2
E 
F

,,,
(simplified somewhat)
```

and needs read into a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
A.1 B
A.1 C
A.1 D
A.2 E
A.2 F
...
```

There are an uneven number of data lines between A.1, A.2, A.3 etc
A.1, A.2, etc are all flagged with a certain text value so easily distinguished.

Comment: please provide samples of code you have tried.

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as as accepted if it helped you in thinking through the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and needs read into a pandas DataFrame like this

I do not believe pandas has any features to support reading the data file directly into the format you are wanting. Instead read it into pandas and than then use the pandas api, such as `apply` to create a new column, etc. This is just one possible way, not saying it is very panda-ish.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(['A.1','B','C','D','A.2','E','F'])

def stacker(row):
    s = row[0]
    return s if '.' in s else np.nan    
df['section'] = df.apply(stacker, axis=1)
print(df.fillna(method='pad'))

# now there is a new column with the expected values
# some additional cleaning would be required to cut out some of the rows

     0 section
0  A.1     A.1
1    B     A.1
2    C     A.1
3    D     A.1
4  A.2     A.2
5    E     A.2
6    F     A.2
```